# Hiding form elements in MS Access

Tags: microsoft-access, forms

Part of my assignment is to create a MS Access form for a user to easily add new customers, caravans etc to our database. In the form design, I have a ListBox control with all the available actions for that user, and when they select a list box item, I want the form to change to reflect their choice. Basically, I want to hide/show form controls based on what the user has selected.

I've managed to respond to a change in the list box selection, but I'm having trouble hiding form elements. There can be upwards of 10 controls that need hiding, and I don't want to create a macro for each one. I had the idea to wrap them in a group box and hide that, but it only hides the group box and not the controls inside of it.

Is there any way to hide 10+ controls in a form easily, rather than creating a macro for each one? I should note aswell that we're not allowed to use any Visual Basic code.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Without using the functionality of VBA or macros, I just don't know how you'd be able to hide controls based on user actions. The form has to have a way to know what to do and when to do it. When a choice is made in the list box, what determines if  other controls need to be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to hide/unhidden form controls without the use of macros/vba within ms access.